# RegEx to extract text between a HTML tag

Tags: java, regex

I'm looking a regular expression which must extract text between HTML tag of different types.

For ex:

`<span>Span 1</span>`  -  O/p: **Span 1**

`<div onclick="callMe()">Span 2</div>` - O/p: **Span 2**

`<a href="#">HyperText</a>` - O/p: **HyperText**

I found this particular piece `<([A-Z][A-Z0-9]*)\b[^>]*>(.*?)</\1>` from [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/examples.html) But this one is not working.

Comment: Please state exactly how it is not working.

Comment: I would like to refer you to the legendary top answer of this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Comment: Your best bet is to use a HTML parser. Something like http://jsoup.org/.

Comment: @MikeM it is not working I mean, it is not giving the desired result. It failed to extract the the content instead it is showing the entire HTML tag

Comment: @Philipp I had gone through that but couldn't find the exact answer.

Comment: @MikeM Yes. It is in the second group. Using java like this `<span>test</span>.replaceAll(patt, "$2")`

Comment: @Sriram The exact answer is: **Don't use regular expressions to parse HTML**, in case that wasn't obvious enough.

Comment: @MikeM I already provided - `"<span>test</span>".replaceAll(patt, "$2")` My intention of the above expression is to bring **test** as an o/p. but it is showing the entire the text as it is.

Comment: @MikeM I guess I should be more clear - `String outPut = "<span>test</span>".replaceAll("<([A-Z][A-Z0-9]*)\b[^>]*>(.*?)</\1>", "$2"); System.out.println(outPut);`

Comment: Use `"<([A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9]*)\\b[^>]*>(.*?)</\\1>"`.

Comment: @MikeM You are brilliant. It worked charm. Thanks! Is it possible to check this recursively? I mean for nested tags like `<span><strong>sriram</strong></span>`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your comment shows that you have neglected to escape the backslashes in your regex string.

And if you want to match lowercase letters add `a-z` to the character classes or use `Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE` (or add `(?i)` to the beginning of the regex)

```
"<([A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9]*)\\b[^>]*>(.*?)</\\1>"
```

If the tag contents may contain newlines, then use `Pattern.DOTALL` or add `(?s)` to the beginning of the regex to turn on dotall/singleline mode.

Comment: Thanks for this. Yep I missed to add backslash in the expression. I'm looking for one more option in that expression which would recursively check the html tags and ultimately get the text between these tags. **Ex:** `<span><strong>test</strong></span>` I hope this time I'm very clear.

Comment: @Sriram. To get the inner tags you would have to use the above regex in a loop, but I think you would be better to ask a new question for that.

Comment: I am unable to retrive the content between the below tag                         <h1><h1>Ajay has no watch</h1></h1><par>So wait for a while to get time </par>                                                                                               Please provide some solution

Answer (score 1):

This should suit your needs:

```
<([a-zA-Z]+).*?>(.*?)</\\1>
```

The first group contains the tag name, the second one the value inbetween.

Comment: If multi tags are there the reg expression is not valid

Answer (score 1):

```
Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("<([a-zA-Z]+).*>(.+)</\\1+>")
    .matcher("<a href=\"#\">HyperText</a>");

while (matcher.find())
{
    String matched = matcher.group(2);

    System.out.println(matched + " found at "
        + "\n"
        + "start at :- " + matcher.start()
        + "\n"
        + "end at :- " + matcher.end()
        + "\n");
}
```

Answer (score -1):

A very specific way:

```
(<span>|<a href="#">|<div onclick="callMe\(\)">)(.*)(</span>|</a>|</div>)
```

but yeah, this will only work for those 3 examples. You'll need to use an HTML parser.

Comment: the case may be with any of the HTML tag. can't say.