# How come I cannot explode a <ul></ul> in php?

Tags: php, html-lists, explode

I am trying to explode 'ul' to get the text. Code below,  Help, appreciate.

```html
<?php
$html="<ul id='get_user' class='get_user'>1,2,3,4</ul>";
$first_explode=("<ul id='get_user' class='get_user'>",$html);
$second_explode=("</ul>", first_explode[1]);
$thrid_explode=(",", $second_explode[0]);
echo $thrid_explode[1]; //expecting 2
?>
```

Comment: is that the whole real string?

Comment: Have you heard of this new thing called Regular Expressions?

Comment: what is Regular Expressions?

Comment: if it is all as you show above, all you need is http://php.net/strip_tags

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just with this.

```
<?php
    $html ="<ul id='get_user' class='get_user'>1,2,3,4</ul>";
    $arrayUL = explode(",", strip_tags($html));
    print_r($arrayUL);
?>
```

[strip_tags Manual](http://php.net/strip_tags)

Comment: can't imagine where you came up with that idea.

Comment: i just wanna help n solving.

Comment: Thanks for your help. You solve my question. but unfortunately, I cannot solve my problem. Because I use .ajax to return the text to a <ul>, so it doesn't work. Thanks anyway.

Comment: whats the problem..? u can use json in .ajax to get return data form php side.

Comment: I don't know what the problem is. I can echo <ul></u> with ajax $("#get_user").text(data); , but when I use strip_tags, it echo nothing, if I put some text between<ul></ul>, it will echo that text. I don't understand.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this Stackoverflow answer: [RegEx to extract text between a HTML tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15685570/regex-to-extract-text-between-a-html-tag)

The regex `"/<([A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9]*)\b[^>]*>(.*?)<\/\1>/"` will extract text within HTML tags. You can use php's preg_match: http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php

Like so:

```
$regex = '/<([A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9]*)\b[^>]*>(.*?)<\/\1>/';
$string = '<div class="some-class" style="display:block;">Hello</div>';
preg_match($regex, $string, $matches);
print_r($matches);
```

In summary, you want to use a Regular Expressions for parsing anything more complicated than simple character delimiters. Here's a handy online regular expression tester: https://regex101.com/#pcre

Comment: you should never use  Regular Expressions for parsing html. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6751105/why-its-not-possible-to-use-regex-to-parse-html-xml-a-formal-explanation-in-la

Comment: Thanks for you time. But I copy and paste your code exactly to test. It doesn't work. Did you miss something or probably I don't know how to use it.

Comment: @Dagon it's a matter of usage -- if it's a single line of HTML you need to parse, it works quite well. Obviously for larger endeavors, use an XML DOM parser. http://stackoverflow.com/a/6752487/1000437